# How to heighlight the sticky subnav menu option on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using intersection observer to hide or show the sticky navbar and make scroll bar sticky.
Now i want to implement one more functionality to make the sub nav options highlight with some color as we scrolls and that particular id container near to the sticky navbar when ever we scrolls.

I have tried some ways i am able to achieve it not working as expected

Here what i have tried.

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <div id="sticky-nav" class="sticky-nav">
      <a>menu1</a>
      <a>menu2</a>
      <a>menu3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <div class="content-div" id="div1">Div 1</div>
      <div class="content-div" id="div2">Div 2</div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const options = {
      root: null, // use viewport as root
      threshold: 0.5, // Adjust as needed
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      this.handleIntersection,
      options
    );
    observer.observe(document.getElementById('content'));
  },
  methods: {
    handleIntersection(entries) {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          const stickyNavHeight = document.getElementById('sticky-nav').clientHeight;
          const div1Top = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop - stickyNavHeight;
          const div2Top = document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop - stickyNavHeight;
          // Get position of other divs similarly
          
          console.log('Position of Div 1:', div1Top);
          console.log('Position of Div 2:', div2Top);
          // Output other div positions as needed
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.sticky-nav {
  /* Style your sticky navigation bar here */
}

.content {
  /* Style your content here */
}

.content-div {
  /* Style your content divs here */
}
</style>
```

**Expected solution:**
Need the div(div1 or div2 or ...) which is closer to id="sticky-nav" when we scroll.

or if there is any other approach that is also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="sticky-nav">
      <a :class="{ active: activeSection === 'div1' }" @click="scrollToSection('div1')">Menu 1</a>
      <a :class="{ active: activeSection === 'div2' }" @click="scrollToSection('div2')">Menu 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-div" id="div1">Div 1</div>
      <div class="content-div" id="div2">Div 2</div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeSection: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll() {
      const stickyNavHeight = document.querySelector('.sticky-nav').clientHeight;
      const div1Top = document.getElementById('div1').offsetTop - stickyNavHeight;
      const div2Top = document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop - stickyNavHeight;
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      
      if (scrollPosition >= div1Top && scrollPosition < div2Top) {
        this.activeSection = 'div1';
      } else if (scrollPosition >= div2Top) {
        this.activeSection = 'div2';
      } else {
        this.activeSection = null;
      }
    },
    scrollToSection(sectionId) {
      const sectionTop = document.getElementById(sectionId).offsetTop;
      const stickyNavHeight = document.querySelector('.sticky-nav').clientHeight;
      window.scrollTo({
        top: sectionTop - stickyNavHeight,
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.sticky-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.sticky-nav a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.sticky-nav a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff0000;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.content-div {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).